# Different results in tensorflow prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I cannot understand why the following codes gives different results. I'm printing the first 3 components of the prediction array to compare results. `my_features` and `feat` have totally different results, but they should be the same, given the model and the data are the same. There should be something wrong in the loading and image preprocessing, but I cannot find it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV3Small
from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

model= MobileNetV3Small(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')

DatasetPath= "DB"
imagePathList= sorted(os.listdir(DatasetPath))
imagePathList= [os.path.join(DatasetPath, imagePath) for imagePath in imagePathList]

def read_image(filename):
    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [224,224])
    image = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3.preprocess_input(image)
    return image


ds_imagePathList= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(imagePathList)
dataset = ds_imagePathList.map(read_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(32, drop_remainder=False)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
my_features = model.predict(dataset)

my_features[0][:3]
```

Second snippet

```
def loadProcessedImage(path):
    #img = image.load_img(path, target_size=model.input_shape[1:3])
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size= (224,224,3))
    imgP = image.img_to_array(img)
    imgP = np.expand_dims(imgP, axis=0)
    imgP = preprocess_input(imgP)
    return img, imgP

img, x = loadProcessedImage(imagePathList[0])
feat = model.predict(x)

feat = feat.flatten()
feat[:3]
```

Comment: Can you set dct_method='INTEGER_ACCURATE' for tf.image.decode_jpeg, check- stackoverflow.com/questions/44514897/…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the image resize. In the second snippet there is a call to `load_img` which internally uses `pillow` to load and resize the image. The problem is that `tf.image.resize` is not correct [see here](https://hackernoon.com/how-tensorflows-tf-image-resize-stole-60-days-of-my-life-aba5eb093f35), and even this a 2018 blog post, the problem is still [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63160350/4267439)